# TextField Space Validation in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, validation, space

I want user to not use any extra spaces in the text field. How to do that?

Description : I have a text field which I am using for "Title of Something". I don't want to allow any user to give extra spaces/only spaces.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here small snippet for UITextFieldDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if([[textField text] length] > 0) {
        if([[textField text] characterAtIndex:([[textField text] length]-1)] == ' ' && 
           [string isEqualToString:@" "]) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trim the string when received:

```
NSString *string = @" spaces in front and at the end ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(trimmedString)
```

Also if you want to remove any double spaces inside the string i think this would do the trick:

```
NSString *noSpaces = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString: @" "];
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me ?(I'm printing it in Log but it's giving me the same string.)

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
 NSString *t1= [txt.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
```